# How to mark some file in debian package as config?

Tags: configuration, dpkg, packaging

I want to make my own Debian package, which contains some default config file. I don't want this file to be rewritten after update with `dpkg -i`.

What are the ways to solve my problem?

Comment: Does [this](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html) help you?

Answer (score 6):

You can create a file called `debian/conffiles` and list the files in it. This will cause `dpkg` to check the file for changes before overwriting it. [From Debian Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ap-pkg-conffiles.html):

> For each file it checks to see whether the version of the file
>   included in the package is the same as the one that was included in
>   the last version of the package (the one that is being upgraded from);
>   it also compares the version currently installed on the system with
>   the one shipped with the last version.
>
> If neither the user nor the package maintainer has changed the file,
>   it is left alone. If one or the other has changed their version, then
>   the changed version is preferred - i.e., if the user edits their file,
>   but the package maintainer doesn't ship a different version, the
>   user's changes will stay, silently, but if the maintainer ships a new
>   version and the user hasn't edited it the new version will be
>   installed (with an informative message). If both have changed their
>   version the user is prompted about the problem and must resolve the
>   differences themselves.

If you really never want `dpkg` to touch the file again, another approach is to just create the file in the `postinst` script on first install and don't do anything on upgrades. Just remember to also create a corresponding `postrm` script that will delete the file on purge.